# Get Items Lookup Mult timeout

Tags: lookup-column, caml, time-out

I have a list with many records , and when I'm doing a filter for a column that is Lookup Multiple runs smoothly :
Example

```
<Where>
    <Eq>
      <FieldRef Name='Column' LookupId='TRUE' />
      <Value Type='Lookup'>2</Value>
    </Eq>
</Where>
<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Title' /></OrderBy>
```

However when I try to make a filter for another item and this item has more than 6k of an error timeout

Caml:

```
<Where>
    <Eq>
      <FieldRef Name='Column' LookupId='TRUE' />
      <Value Type='Lookup'>1</Value>
    </Eq>
</Where>
<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Title' /></OrderBy>
```

Error:

```
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetListItemDataWithCallback2(IListItemSqlClient pSqlClient, String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String bstrViewName, String bstrViewXml, SAFEARRAYFLAGS fSafeArrayFlags, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pSACallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingCallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingPrevCallback, ISPDataCallback pFilterLinkCallback, ISPDataCallback pSchemaCallback, ISPDataCallback pRowCountCallback, Boolean& pbMaximalView) 
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetListItemDataWithCallback2(IListItemSqlClient pSqlClient, String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String bstrViewName, String bstrViewXml, SAFEARRAYFLAGS fSafeArrayFlags, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pSACallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingCallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingPrevCallback, ISPDataCallback pFilterLinkCallback, ISPDataCallback pSchemaCallback, ISPDataCallback pRowCountCallback, Boolean& pbMaximalView) 
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection.EnsureListItemsData() 
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection.get_Count()
```

Note I'm using the RowLimit = 20.
Have any alternative for this error?

Comment: What is the lookup threshold on the list?

Comment: List View Lookup Threshold: 50

Comment: List View Threshold: +500k

Comment: how many items are there total in the list? What do the ULS Logs say?

Comment: the total number of items is +164 k. I never saw the uls log

Comment: How many items do you estimate match #1, and how many items would match #2?  Try taking out the orderby and see if that makes a difference.  I realize that will not work like you'd like, but it will help identify if your problem is